# Appending an int to a wchar_t*? ..unresolved, lack of concrete example

Tags: c++

I am building a string of `int` values, stored in a `wchar_t*`.  If I have an integer, how can I append it onto the end of a `wchar_t*`?  Windows only solutions are fine for this and I'd rather not include boost :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a wide version of stringstream and the '<<' operator. The correct operator to perform the conversion for you should be defined.

If I am missing some subtlety here you could depend on boost and use [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

I'm still a fan of secure versions of sprintf and so is [Herb Sutter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=exceptional+c%2B%2B+style&x=0&y=0) :D.

Comment: stringstreambuffer?  can you possibly give an example?

Comment: sorry, its actually called a stringstream. it works like std::cout. You pump data into it -- like cout, and at the end you can retrieve a string from the stringstream. You can find a reference from www.cplusplus.com. If this doesn't help than I will post a more detailed example, please advise.

Comment: Example: `std::wstringstream ss; ss << 1; ss << 2; std::string s = ss.str();`

Comment: yep that is it, thanks pavel. Was too drunk to think last night :P

Comment: Thanks a lot.  However, after that cast I'm still not sure how you could append the two... I'll do some research.  Thanks

Comment: Ok let me see if I can clarify things for you. StringStream is a stream that you can stream data into, just like cout. stringstream dynamically builds up a string from the input you supply -- growing the underlying buffer as needed. It keeps a ptr to the head of the string and all data gets added there. So to supply hello world as distinct words it would be: `ss << "Hello" << " " << "World" << "!" << "\n";` or you could break down the operations like pavel did above.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using windows you can always use wsprintf ie

```
wsprintf( newStr, L"%s%d", oldStr, yourInt );
```

I'm sure there will be some equivalent for non-windows ...

Comment: I allready used that as an answer, + suggesting sprintf before managed objects is not good when the tags imply c++ and newbie. Plus you have not picked the secure version of the function, (-1) for this reason. –

Comment: Pah ... nowt wrong with using a C solution to a C++ question.  Half the reason a lot of C++ programmers wrie such awful code is this perceived need to only use OO constructs.  OO is a useful tool but ISN'T the be all and end all ... BRING ON THE DOWNVOTES >:D

Comment: So this makes a brand new string?  is it specific ot a certain type of string?

Answer (score 0):

How about boost lexical_cast<>

```
std::wstring  data;

data += boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>(53);
data.c_str() // This is wchar_t*
```